# Cannot save and display data in table view correctly with Core Data and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Goal:

My goal is to pass the current minimum, average and maximum value data to table view and present them to the user.

Error:

When I hit the "Save" button "nan" value is passed with the current minimum, average and maximum value data.

UI screenshot

[image]

Here is the table view before pressing the Save button

[image]

Here is the table view after pressing the Save button

[image]

Here is the current code:

Record.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Record: NSManagedObject {
    var minimumValue: Float = .nan
    var averageValue: Float = .nan
    var maximumValue: Float = .nan
}
```

RecordTableViewController.swift

```
class RecordCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var maximumValueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var averageValueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var minimumValueLabel: UILabel!
}

class RecordTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    private lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = { () -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> in
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "History")
        let sortDescriptor: [NSSortDescriptor] = []
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptor

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        return fetchedResultsController
    }()

    let cellIdentifier: String = "cellID"
    var recordsArray = [Record]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeRight(_:)))
        swipe.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)

        recordsArray = fetchAllRecords()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch editingStyle {
        case .delete:
            let removedRecord = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
            let context = fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
            context.delete(removedRecord)

            do {
                try context.save()
                self.recordsArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            } catch _ {

            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

extension RecordTableViewController {
    public func fetchAllRecords() -> [Record] {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "History")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            return result as! [Record]
        } catch let error {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Dispatch
import CoreData
import Accelerate
import Foundation
import UserNotifications

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    var minimum: Float = .nan
    var average: Float = .nan
    var maximum: Float = .nan
    var decibel: Float = .nan

    /// MARK: Segue functions

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "saveRecord" {
            let recordVC = segue.destination as! RecordTableViewController
            let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
            let record = Record.init(entity: NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "History", in: context)!, insertInto: context)

            record.minimumValue = Float(minDbLabel.text!) ?? 0.0
            record.averageValue = Float(averageDbLabel.text!) ?? 0.0
            record.maximumValue = Float(maximumDbLabel.text!) ?? 0.0

            saveNewRecord(record: record)

            self.recordsArray.append(record)
            recordVC.recordsArray = self.recordsArray
        }
    }

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: UIButton){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveRecord", sender: nil)
    }

    // MARK: Core Data functions

    private func saveNewRecord(record: Record) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        var index: Int = 0

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "History", in: context)
        let newRecord = [NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)] as [NSManagedObject]

        newRecord[index].setValue(record.minimumValue, forKey: "minimumValue")
        newRecord[index].setValue(record.averageValue, forKey: "averageValue")
        newRecord[index].setValue(record.maximumValue, forKey: "maximumValue")
        index += 1

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you work with Core Data the name of the entity is "History" but the type you use in your table view is `Record`, this is very confusing. And you have a `NSFetchedResultsController` but you don't use it to fetch, why?

Comment: Why do you insert a new object in `prepare(for` and then you call a method to insert another new object copying the values from the former to the latter? And you are encouraged to take advantage of the generic potential of Core Data.

Comment: Also, in `RecordTableViewController` you are using an `NSFetchedResultsController` - You should use its `delegate` methods to handle insertion/deletion etc

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is kinda confusing, however, here's how I setup my CoreData applications.

**First: I create a CoreDataManager model** 
This will handle all of my Model functions like fetching viewing and context etc...

```
struct CoreDataManager {
  static let shared = CoreDataManager()

  let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let perCon = NSPersistentContainer(name: "EntityName")
    perCon.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, err) in
      if let err = err {
        fatalError("\(err)")
      }
    }
    return perCon
  }()

  func fetchEntitys() -> [Entity] {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Entity>(entityName: "EntityName")
    do {
      let entity = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
      return entity
    } catch let err {
      print("\(err)")
      return []
    }
  }

  func resetEntitys() {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    let batchRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: Entity.fetchRequest())
    do {
      try context.execute(batchRequest)
    } catch let err {
      print("\(err)")
    }
  }
}
```

**Second: Setup your secondViewController *the viewController in which you create the objects in***

1. You would need to create a delegate for this viewController

```
protocol CreateControllerDelegate: class {
  func didAdd(entity: Entity)
}
```

2. In your secondViewController *in this case, it's CreateController* you should add the following property.

```
weak var delegate: CreateControllerDelegate?
```

3. Implement the function in which you will save objects into your CoreData.

```
  func createEntity() {
    let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "EntityName", into: context)
    entity.setValue(nameTextField.text, forKey: "name") 
    // set all of your values that you want to be saved.
    do {
      try context.save()
      dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.delegate?.didAdd(entity: entity as! Entity)
      }
    } catch {
      let nserror = error as NSError
      fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }
  }
```

**Finally, setup your firstViewController *the one in which you will display all of your Core Data objects.***

1. Add a property to your MainController in which it will hold all of your Entity objects.

```
var objectsArray = [Entity]()
```

2. Inside of your MainController's viewDidLoad function add the following.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.objectsArray = CoreDataManager.shared.fetchEntitys()
  }
```

3. Confirm and implement the CreateControllerDelegate in your MainController.

```
extension MainController: CreateControllerDelegate {
  func didAdd(entity: Entity) {
    objectsArray.append(entity)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: objectsArray.count - 1, section: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
  }
}
```

4. Push your secondViewController.
   *I don't use Segues.*

```
  @IBAction func handleAdd(_ sender: Any) {
    let createController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CreateController") as! CreateController
    createController.delegate = self
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: createController)
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(navController, animated: true)
  }
```

I hope this is helpful and if there's something that's not working let me know!

Good Luck!